# Elasticsearch - How to get the list of documents with Unique combination of two fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following data in Elasticsearch(6.7) :

```
{
  "first_name": "abc",
  "last_name": "def",
  "sat":900,
  "description":"desc1" 
}
{
  "first_name": "abc",
  "last_name": "def",
  "sat":1100,
  "description":"desc2" 

}
{
  "first_name": "abc",
  "last_name": "ghi",
  "sat":1000,
  "description":"desc3" 

}
```

The result should be only the documents with a **unique set of first_name and last_name**. **And for that unique combination, the sum of sat should be returned. description could be any of the descriptions in that combination.**

The result should be :

```
{
  "first_name": "abc",
  "last_name": "def",
  "sat":2000,
  "description":"desc1"  

}
{
  "first_name": "abc",
  "last_name": "ghi",
  "sat":1000,
  "description":"desc3" 

}
```

I've tried using this query to get the unique combination of firstName and lastName :

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "genres" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source": "doc['first_name.keyword']+''+doc['last_name.keyword']",
                    "lang": "painless"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Can do the nested aggregation in it for the sat sum score. But how do we get the description as well?
Any thoughts on using the script here during the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new auto set filled in the mappings. Script would be pretty slow.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "copy_to": "complete_name"
        },
        "last_name": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "copy_to": "complete_name"
        },
        "complete_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You just have to aggregate on complete_name and add 2 sub agrergation (on desc and sum the  sat)

```
{
   "size" : 0,
   "aggs": {
      "genres": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "complete_name"
         },
         "aggs": { 
            "sum_sat": { 
               "sum": {
                  "field": "sat" 
               }
            }
         },
         "aggs": { 
            "any_desc": { 
               "terms": {
                  "field": "description" 
               },
               "size": 1
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

you can also use tophits aggregation to target the description you want.